# How to create dynamic route if there is no unique id from backend?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, dynamic-routing

When using public API which provide data with unique id I can simple use this id to create dynamic route e.g. ${book.id}. But some API do not provide unique id, so how can I replace my ${book.id} in this case?

Code example that works when id provided:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/book" element={<BooksView />} />
    <Route path="/book/:bookId" element={<BookDetailsView />} />
</Routes>
```

```
return(
{books && (
        <ul>
          {books.map((book) => (
            <li key={book.id}>
              <Link to={`/books/${book.id}`}>{book.title}</Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )})
```

I tried to generate unique id with uuid library but it didn't work, maybe because it creates string type data whereas number type needed

Comment: What would you replace it with?

Comment: Have no idea, but if there is no way to replace it this answer is also fine for me) Then I just will not use public API without id...

Comment: The point is that a "dynamic route" can take whatever its given and use it however it wants, but if it's being used to look something up then it needs to actually **mean** something. The question and/or problem being solved isn't clear.

Comment: Thank you Dave, I guess I understand what you talking about. In my case ":bookId" parameter could be anything, right. But in the Link I have to point the path via book.id and I took it from database. For example, I get 100 books from backend and after clicking on one book I need to go to that one book page, for this, I use id that backend provided. In case there is no id from database I can't go to one book page. This is an issue.

Comment: If a server don’t provide a unique identifier that can be used to identify an entity, regardless of the identifier type, then no, there’s no way to uniquely identify the entity. This would be unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to work with some APIs that returned data either without ids or data partially with ids.

If you need a valid `book.id` property to interface with external (*to the app*) 3rd-party APIs then there's not much you can do here since you can't really make up an id value that would work in this situation.

So long as the `book.id` property is only used locally to navigate to and display fetched content then the way I've solved this issue is to process the data after it's been fetched prior to saving it into any local state, generating and adding ids when necessary. Here's an example workflow.

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

...

const fetchBooks = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(".......");
  const bookData = await response.json();

  const processedBookData = bookData.map(book => !!book.id
    ? book
    : { ...book, id: uuidV4() } // <-- generate id if missing
  );

  /* save processedBookData into books state */
};
```

BooksView - There should now be a defined `id` property for each book object that is sufficiently guaranteed to be unique.

```
return(
  {books && (
    <ul>
      {books.map((book) => (
        <li key={book.id}>
          <Link to={`/books/${book.id}`}>{book.title}</Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )}
);
```

It shouldn't matter if the `book.id` property is a string or number-like ***value*** as all route path params will be a string type when accessing within a component via the `useParams` hook. If you have a mix of "types" then the suggestion here is to use a type-safe comparison by converting all id values to strings for comparison.

BookDetailsView

```js
const BookDetailsView = () => {
  const { bookId } = useParams();

  const book = books.find(book => String(book.id) === bookId);

  if (!book) {
    // book not found
  }

  // book found
  ...
};
```

If you need to generate ids ***and*** interact with external APIs then you could set a flag in the `books` data that indicates if the `id` value is real or not, and use this to conditionally allow any external interactions.

```js
const processedBookData = bookData.map(book => !!book.id
  ? book
  : {
      ...book,
      id: uuidV4(),
      internalId: true
    }
);
```

```js
if (!book.internalId) {
  // id is legitimate, use for external calls/effects
}
```

Comment: Drew, thank you so much for detailed answer, I'll definitely try your suggestions!)